# Find interval over similar column names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, intervals

I'd like a simpler way to find whether a value is within any of the given intervals. Given the dataframe:

```
Value  start1  start2  start3  end1  end2  end3
212    82      195     409     97    220   411
80     57      95      111     69    100   130
```

I'd like to create a new column with a 1 if the 'Value' is in any of the intervals ([start1-end1], [start2-end2], etc) and a 0 if it is not; so in the case above, the first row would have a value of 1 because 212 falls in the second interval and the second row would be a 0. Note that these are the orders of the columns currently and edge cases (value matching the start or end of the interval) should be encoded as a 1.

I could do this with ifelse statements but there are 260 columns and I feel like the solution could be useful in other ways in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(Value=c(212,80), start1=c(82,57), start2=c(195,95), start3=c(409,111),
                end1=c(97,69), end2=c(220,100), end3=c(411,130))

dt[, rowid:= .I]
```

It's more natural to do this with a 'melted' table:

```
dt_melt = melt(dt, id=c('rowid','Value'), measure=patterns('start','end'),
               variable.name='interval', value.name=c('start','end'))

#    rowid Value interval start end
# 1:     1   212        1    82  97
# 2:     2    80        1    57  69
# 3:     1   212        2   195 220
# 4:     2    80        2    95 100
# 5:     1   212        3   409 411
# 6:     2    80        3   111 130
```

Now we can do the computation and merge with `dt` on the rowid:

```
dt[dt_melt[, as.integer(any(between(Value, start, end))), by='rowid'], on='rowid']

#    Value start1 start2 start3 end1 end2 end3 rowid V1
# 1:   212     82    195    409   97  220  411     1  1
# 2:    80     57     95    111   69  100  130     2  0
```

Comment: Is there something I need other than data.table, it says there is no function called 'patterns'?

Comment: Nope, patterns is from data.table. What version are you using

Comment: Nevermind, needed to convert from data.frame to data.table

Comment: Thank you, I should've known to melt the data lol. This will also solve many of my other problems !

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `tidyverse`. The final output is in the `InRange` column of the `dt3` data frame.

```
# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "Value  start1  start2  start3  end1  end2  end3
212    82      195     409     97    220   411
                 80     57      95      111     69    100   130",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Load packages
library(tidyverse)

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>% mutate(GroupID = 1:n()) 

dt3 <- dt2 %>%
  gather(StartEnd, Number, -Value, -GroupID) %>%
  mutate(Type = gsub("[0-9]", "", StartEnd),
         ID = gsub("[a-z]", "", StartEnd)) %>%
  select(-StartEnd) %>%
  spread(Type, Number) %>%
  mutate(InRange = ifelse(Value >= start & Value <= end, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(GroupID) %>%
  summarise(InRange = max(InRange)) %>%
  right_join(dt2, by = "GroupID")
```

Notice that I created the `GroupID` column to make sure duplicated values in the `Value` column, if any, will not affect the analysis. However, if you are certain that there are no duplicated values, you can use the following code, without creating the `GroupID` column. `dt2` is the final output.

```
# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(StartEnd, Number, -Value) %>%
  mutate(Type = gsub("[0-9]", "", StartEnd),
         ID = gsub("[a-z]", "", StartEnd)) %>%
  select(-StartEnd) %>%
  spread(Type, Number) %>%
  mutate(InRange = ifelse(Value >= start & Value <= end, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(Value) %>%
  summarise(InRange = max(InRange)) %>%
  right_join(dt, by = "Value")
```